# Is the price of a waterskin mentioned anywhere?

Tags: equipment, pricing, witcher

In the book for the The Witcher Pen & Paper RPG, there is a list of suggested items for Witchers to buy when they create their character. In this list, "a waterskin" is one of the recommended items (page 71). This item is also listed as being part of Vernon Roche's and Iorveth's gear (page 17, 18). Additionally, it is listed in the Random Possessions table (page 223). But nowhere do I find what a waterskin actually costs! I also checked the 2018 errata (I have an earlier print of the book), and it doesn't seem to be mentioned there either. As such, I ask, is the price of a waterskin mentioned anywhere in any official literature related to this pen and paper RPG, or is this something the game master just has to come up with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just after posting this question a friend sends me a message saying that he's found the 2022 errata of the The Witcher Tabletop RPG, and in it the waterskin is listed as having been added to the General Gear table weighing .1 and costing 8.

The full errata can be found here: https://rtalsoriangames.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/RTG-WI-WitcherCoreErratav4.pdf